# How do I get multiple Records from my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So from what I can tell, I need to be able to return all the records from my Database Model:

```
    public class Resort
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int BlackDiamond { get; set; }
    public int BlueSquare { get; set; }
    public int GreenCircle { get; set; }
    public int TerrainPark { get; set; }
}
public class ResortDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Resort> Resorts { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework, C# and Asp.Net.  I need to be able to return all of these records to a `List<>`

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using now that is only return one record?

Comment: Well I was actually just attempting to iterate through each instance of the model but I don't think that is going to work out too well:          private ResortDBContext dbResort = new ResortDBContext();   Resort resort = dbResort.Resorts.Find(id).   I was originally going to try using a variable to hold the id and then iterate the variable by one each time until resort returned null but I'm pretty sure that won't work...

Comment: Actually as it turns out that worked, I ended up setting up a Do While loop and I had a boolean value as the test, I simply kept iterating the id variable by one until Resort returned null at which point I set my boolean value to false to stop the loop.  Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
        using (var YourContext = new YourEntities())
        {
            List<Resort> resorts = (from resorts in YourContext.Resort
                                    select resorts).ToList();

            foreach (Resort resort in resorts)
            {
                //Do something here
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've gotta be honest, I'm not really sure what's going on in that code up there...

Comment: I suggest that you start reading up on EF perhaps this link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc748673.aspx and this one too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Comment: @Jared - Don't be scared of the `from r` syntax.  It means the same thing as `YourContext.Resort.Select(x => x)`, which is more-or-less the same as just `YourContext.Resort`.  It grabs everything in the `Resort` table from your data context.

Comment: So in this example I find myself wondering what YourContext would be and same with YourEntities?  I apologize if that's a silly question, but I'm here to learn!

Comment: @Jared - That would be the data context you create for connecting to the database.  Read up on the links Mark suggested for some good information and examples.